# Missing App configuration value: "projectId" even though I am passing it in

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

I am able to send, view and click on web notifications fine, and nothing appears wrong. However the console yields this when I click on a notification

```
Uncaught FirebaseError: Messaging: Missing App configuration value: "projectId" (messaging/missing-app-config-values).
```

projectId is definitely being passed to the configuration

Chrome version: Version 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit)

here is how I am configuring firebase:

```
var messaging;
if( firebase.messaging.isSupported() ){

    var config = {
      apiKey: "*************",
      authDomain: "*************",
      databaseURL: "*************",
      projectId: "*************",
      storageBucket: "*************",
      messagingSenderId: "*************",
      appId: "*************"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    messaging = firebase.messaging();
    messaging.usePublicVapidKey("*************");
    messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

And my firebase-messeging-sw.js:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    ...
    ...
}
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.2/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.2/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({'messagingSenderId': '***********'});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
    ...
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to call `initializeApp()` **before** calling any other Firebase APIs.  Your code is calling `firebase.messaging.isSupported()` first before `initializeApp()`.  It looks like perhaps you only want to initialize Firebase if FCM is going to work, but that's simply not supported.  I suggest initializing Firebase unconditionally.  There is very little cost to doing so if you don't actually make use of any of the Firebase products.

Comment: Oddly enough, I updated all the browser service workers, cleared cache and the error went away. Good point in the initialization.

Comment: I do this correctly and nevertheless face this error. frustrated by firebase, 1 weird error after the other

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by modifying the service worker with config details.

### Initializing using the config file

I fixed this issue by giving the congig values inside the service worker itself.

for that copy your config files from `environment.ts` file or from [`FCM console`](https://console.firebase.google.com/)  -> `<your-project>` ->

[image: click on the gear icon] -> `project settings` -> scroll down to `your apps` ->

click on `<your-app>` -> copy the `config`.

now paste this `config` in `firebase-messaging-sw.ts` inside the `firebase.initializeApp()` as

```
firebase.initializeApp({
  'messagingSenderId': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'apiKey': "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  'authDomain': "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  'databaseURL': "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  'projectId': "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  'storageBucket': "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  'messagingSenderId': "599149435887",
  'appId': "x:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  'measurementId': "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
});
```

this worked for me, hope it work for you too.

### ALternative method (long shot, not sure if works)

one other thing worked for is that reducing the version in

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.7.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.7.0/firebase-messaging.js');
```

to

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.0/firebase-messaging.js');
```

but in this case I couldn't get any notification, maybe if it works for you, you can use this also.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by re-getting my app's config snippet from here https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592 and paste it again as my initializeApp object parameter. It was apparently caused by a Firebase upgrade.